# Read td values by tr id from the same table

Tags: javascript, jquery, row

I am trying to read the values of table based on the tr id, but cannot wrap my head around how to do this.

```
    // Id of the tr in question for example.row_17 
    var d =c["id"]; 
    console.log(d); 

    // Here I can read all the td values, but I only want
    // the ones inside the tr id = "row_17" 

    var cols =document.getElementById('report_table').getElementsByTagName('td'), 

     colslen = cols.length, i = -1; > while(++i < colslen)
    {  console.log(cols[i].innerHTML); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged it with jQuery, you can do it by doing something like this:

```
var id = c["id"];

// Select only the row with id specified in 'id' and loop through all 'td's' of that row.
$("#" + id).find("td").each(function()
{
    // Log the html content of each 'td'.
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Yes, that suits me fine. Thank you very much. I´ll accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want a solution for JavaScript only (no jQuery):

```
var id = c["id"];

var tds = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id + ' td');
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    console.log(tds[i].innerHTML);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/18doqpgx/)